# Navibar and full page slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just wanted to place my bootstrap nav bar inside the full width slider just like this.

[image]

```
This is the full width slider
```

http://codepen.io/grovesdm/pen/MazqzQ

I've placed the nav bar on top and put slider code after that. Now it's looks like this.

[image]

If I remove the nav bar background color and make that div transparent, nothing happened. If I need to place the slider inside the slider?

Comment: Why not give the navbar an absolute position of top:0 left:0?

Comment: The nav bar is on top of your slider, not inside it. A transparent navbar shows just the background of `<body>` or whatever's it's standing upon

Comment: @jbrya029 This is the current styles for slider `position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;`

Comment: @JohnSmith You are correct. It shows body background color. I need to place my slider behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this :

```js
/*! http://mths.be/slideshow v1.0.0 by @mathias */ ;
(function($) {
  $.fn.slideshow = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      'timeout': 3000,
      'speed': 400 // 'normal'
    }, options);
    // We loop through the selected elements, in case the slideshow was called on more than one element e.g. `$('.foo, .bar').slideShow();`
    return this.each(function() {
      // Inside the setInterval() block, `this` references the window object instead of the slideshow container element, so we store it inside a var
      var $elem = $(this);
      $elem.children().eq(0).appendTo($elem).show();
      // Iterate through the slides
      setInterval(function() {
        $elem.children().eq(0)
          // Hide the current slide and append it to the end of the image stack
          .hide().appendTo($elem) // As of jQuery 1.3.2, .appendTo() returns the inserted element
          // Fade in the next slide
          .fadeIn(options.speed)
      }, options.timeout);
    });
  };
}(jQuery));

// Name the slider

$(function() {
  $('.slider').slideshow({
    timeout: 7000,
    speed: 1000
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/*section {
  border: 10px solid green;
}

body {
  border: 10px solid orange;
}*/

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.slider li .slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider li .slide figcaption {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
<section>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  
    <ul class="slider">
      <li>
        <figure class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/260511/1d9326c2ae66befef4e39c3426adf17a.jpg)">
          <figcaption>hello</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/260511/______by_Thoum.jpg)">
          <figcaption>yeah</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <p>Hello</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes. This is I want. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know it helped :)

Comment: But one thing. The nav far fixed to top. But I Don't need fixed nav bar at the moment. How can I fixed that?

Comment: In the `<nav>` class remove `navbar-fixed-top`.

Comment: I did. But it turned back to the default again.